# Pointer or a reference

Tags: c++, oop, reference, this

I am building a c++ program for handling complex numbers.
I am having problem with the behaviour of this code:

```
Complex& Complex::operator=(const Complex& com)
{
    Complex::re_=com.re_;
    Complex::im_=com.im_;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, the return type of this function is a reference of Complex type. So shouldn't I be passing `this` rather than `*this`.

Comment: No, `this` is a pointer to the instance of `Complex` and needs to be deferenced for the `return`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` pointer is the address of your object instance.

Use an asterisk to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in Java and C#, `this` is not a reference in C++, it's a pointer. That pointer is either of type `Complex*` or `Complex const*`, depending on the const qualifier on the method (so it's `Complex*` in your case).

**Edit:** as noted in the comments, references of Java and C# are not that easily comparable to references and poitners in C++, so let me clarify:

*Syntactically*, references of all three languages are treated the same, i.e. they don't need to be dereferenced or are dereferenced implicitly, or, simply put, you access the object behind it like `ref.method()`.

*Semantically*, normal Java and C# references behave like C++ pointers, i.e. they can be null and they can be reassigned to point to another object. In C++, neither is possible with references. So at first sight, `this` in Java and C# has C++ pointer semantics like it has in C++. But since it cannot be `null` and cannot be reassigned to point to another object, that semantic difference disappears and it has the same C++-reference semantics in all three languages.

So, same answer in other words:
**Although `this` has reference semantics, it is syntactically a pointer in C++, so you have to explicitly dereference it to get a (syntactic) reference.**

Comment: `this` is a pointer because it can be NULL.  (It shouldn't be, but it can be.)

Comment: No, `this` can never be NULL i a standard conforming way. If you call a method on a null pointer, you get UB. So that is not a valid reason to make `this` a pointer. Implementations that don't crash on dereferencing a null-pointer could be done with a reference-`this` as well - you would have `this` being some dangling null reference - so what, it's UB anyways.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that `this` is a pointer for hysterical^Whistorical reasons. References wasn't available in the very first generation of C++, and to keep compatibility, it has to be kept that way.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that primordial C++ had no references. Another thing that can't be done with a this reference is `delete this;`

Comment: This is an incorrect comparison. `this` in Java and C# are pointers. References in Java and C# are pointers to objects. It's not the C++ "reference".

Comment: @newacct yes and no. In Java and C# there are no pointers, although the references in those languages semantically behave like C++ pointers, in terms that they can be null and reassigned. But since neither is the case for `this`, it is the same like a C++ reference.

Comment: @ArneMertz: `final` references also cannot be reassigned, but that doesn't make them different. The difference between a pointer and C++ reference is not "they can be null and reassigned" -- there's also the fact that `new Something` has type pointer and not reference, and that you can only make a pointer from an object value with `&`, but a reference from an object value directly. Finally, the Java Language Specification specifically says that references are pointers to objects. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1